# Why does modulus (%) operator work for char but not for floating types?

Tags: c, floating-point, operators, modulus

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char c;
  c=10;
  if(c%2==0)
    printf("Yes");
  return 0;
}
```

The above code prints "Yes". Can someone tell why the modulus operator works for `char` and `int` but not for `double` etc.?

Comment: Because `char` is an integer type.  For floating-point types, use `fmod()`.

Comment: Because `char` is an 8-bit integer.  `double` is not an integer.

Comment: @HotLicks `char` is an **at least** 8-bit integer. However, since one can easily define a modulo operation on non-integral numbers, that doesn't really answer the question. (To a "why"-style question, the only answer is probably "because that's how the C standard defines it".)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: If the question is "why is it so?", then the answer can only be "because the language standard says so".  Of course, it's worth pointing out that the characteristics of floating-point arithmetic mean that a "modulo" operator wouldn't always do what one would hope.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Exactly. Let me add that too. (re FP characteristics: nor does addition, multiplication or practically any other FP operation, but they still do have their own operators. It would be perfectly reasonable for `%` to work with floating-point types as well.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Not necessarily.  The `%` operator for integers is defined in terms of `/`; that equality doesn't necessarily hold in floating-point arithmetic.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth and what about other operators? `*` and `/` are defined for both integral and floating-point types, although they don't do the same thing either (identities such as `a * b / b == a` hold for integers, but not for FP types). So why couldn't be `%` defined as well? Knowing about the inexact nature of floating-point arithmetic, one would expect that `a / b * b + a % b != a`. (Also, since integers and floating-point numbers are different types, there's no problem defining a certain operation a bit differently on them.)

Comment: @theparamagneticcroissant: yes, that's fair. Nevertheless, the standard is what it is ;)

Comment: I think most of these comments should be answer, not just comments >o<

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yep, definitely :) And I'm fine with that, just trying to justify OP's question :P

Comment: Although similar, `%` is better called the _remainder_ operator and not _modulus_; that what the C spec calls it.  [Ben](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16585325/why-7-5-gives-2-but-75-gives-2-shouldnt-it-be-2-in-both-cases/16585491#16585491) has good references to the differences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already got comments explaining why `%` is defined for `char`: it's defined for all integer types, and in C, `char` is an integer type. Some other languages do define a distinct `char` type that does not support arithmetic operations, but C is not one of them.

But to answer why it isn't defined for floating-point types: history. There is no technical reason why it wouldn't be possible to define the `%` operator for floating-point types. Here's what the C99 rationale says:

> **6.5.5 Multiplicative operators**
>
> [...]
>
> The C89 Committee rejected extending the `%` operator to work on floating types as such usage would duplicate the facility provided by `fmod` (see §7.12.10.1).

And as mafso found later:

> **7.12.10.1 The fmod functions**
>
> [...]
>
> The C89 Committee considered a proposal to use the remainder operator `%` for this function; but it was rejected because the operators in general correspond to hardware facilities, and `fmod` is not supported in hardware on most machines.

They seem somewhat contradictory. The `%` operator was not extended because `fmod` already filled that need, but `fmod` was picked to fill that need because the committee did not want to extend the `%` operator? They cannot very well both be true at the same time.

I suspect one of these reasons was the original reason, and the other was the reason for not later re-visiting that decision, but there's no telling which was first. Either way, it was simply decided that `%` wouldn't perform this operation.

Comment: I'd suggest adding (ibid. 7.12.10.1 p.5) “The C89 Committee considered a proposal to use the remainder operator `%` for this function; but it was rejected because the operators in general correspond to hardware facilities, and `fmod` is not supported in hardware on most machines.”

Comment: @mafso Thanks, but huh, that's odd. That seems to contradict what I found.

Comment: It's just another reason given in the same document, though it's a little odd to have "A, because X" at one place and at another "A, because Y" instead of just "A, because X and Y". But I don't see a contradiction.

Comment: @mafso I see it more as "A, because B", and "B, because A", and suspect both have been correct at some point, but never both at the same time.

Comment: I see your point. I read the former as "there's no need for an operator, because a function can do that" (and the latter as "would be against the spirit of C"), not as "we already have this function, so there's no need for an operator (and if we had processed the proposals in a different order, we could have omitted `fmod` and define the operator instead)".